# Laravel mysql insert+delete or update how?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am scrapping a website for news and saving that in a database, however this 'job' or function will be running every hour and therefore to reduce number of records I keep it down to 20 records, now of course I don't want to keep old news therefore I want to either insert new query and delete previous one or update existing one. Number of records is always 20, but how  will that be done? Surely, if I do insert+delete, id number will change each time. However if I do an update, how will I tell it to update first 1-20 id's.

Here's how it looks like in a database:

[image]

And here's code so far:

```
function oldham_chronicle(){
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features');
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node) {
        $test = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $test2 = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $news = new News();
        $news->title = $test;
        $news->datepublished = $test2;
        $news->save();
    });
return view('chronicle');
```

Comment: Have you tried the migrate syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to update, you can try with this

```
function oldham_chronicle(){
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features');
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $test = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $test2 = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $id = $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();

        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }

        $news->title = $test;
        $news->datepublished = $test2;
        $news->save();
    });
return view('chronicle');
```

I haven't test my code, because I don't have the data.

Comment: works brilliant! What if there isn't id = 1 so basically if there is no record insert, if there is, update instead?